# Unable to fix the issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

Below is the code that is being run but was unable to figure out the exact problem as what needs to be changed to fix this up.

```
package com.totsy.test;    
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.totsy.xls.read.Xls_Reader;
public class DriverScript {

public static Logger APP_LOGS;
//suite.xlsx
public Xls_Reader suiteXLS;
public int currentSuiteID;
public String currentTestSuite;
private boolean isColExist;
private String colName;


//Current test suite
public static Xls_Reader currentTestSuiteXLS;
public static int currentTestCaseID;
public static String currentTestCaseName;
public static int currentTestStepID;
public static String currentKeyword;
public static int currentTestDataSetID=2;
public static Method method[];
public static Method capturescreenshot_method;
public static Keywords keywords;
public static String keyword_execution_result;
public static ArrayList<String>resultSet;
public static String data;
public static String object;


// properties

public static Properties CONFIG;
public static Properties OR;



public DriverScript() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
    keywords = new Keywords();
    method = keywords.getClass().getMethods();
    capturescreenshot_method =keywords.getClass().getMethod("captureScreenshot",String.class,String.class);
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    {
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("src/test/java/com/totsy/config/config.properties");
    CONFIG= new Properties();
    CONFIG.load(fs);

    fs = new FileInputStream("src/test/java/com/totsy/config/or.properties");
    OR= new Properties();
    OR.load(fs);

    //System.out.println(CONFIG.getProperty("testsiteURL"));
    //System.out.println(OR.getProperty("name"));


    DriverScript test = new DriverScript();
    test.start();
    }


}





public void start() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
    // initialize the app logs
    APP_LOGS = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
    APP_LOGS.debug("Hello");
    APP_LOGS.debug("Properties loaded. Starting testing");
    // 1) check the runmode of test Suite
    // 2) Runmode of the test case in test suite
    // 3) Execute keywords of the test case serially
    // 4) Execute Keywords as many times as
    // number of data sets - set to Y
    APP_LOGS.debug("Intialize Suite xlsx");
    suiteXLS = new Xls_Reader("src/test/java/com/totsy/xls/Suite.xlsx");



    for(currentSuiteID=2;currentSuiteID<=suiteXLS.getRowCount(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET);currentSuiteID++)
    {
        APP_LOGS.debug(suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.Test_Suite_ID, currentSuiteID)+" -- "+  suiteXLS.getCellData("Test Suite", "Runmode", currentSuiteID));


        // test suite name = test suite xls file having test cases
        currentTestSuite=suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.Test_Suite_ID, currentSuiteID);

        if(suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.RUNMODE, currentSuiteID).equals(Constants.RUNMODE_YES))

        {
            // execute the test cases in the suite
            APP_LOGS.debug("******Executing the Suite******"+suiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_SUITE_SHEET, Constants.Test_Suite_ID, currentSuiteID));


            currentTestSuiteXLS=new Xls_Reader("src/test/java/com/totsy/xls/"+currentTestSuite+".xlsx");

            //iterate through all the test cases in the suite

            for(currentTestCaseID=2;currentTestCaseID<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount("Test Cases");currentTestCaseID++){


                APP_LOGS.debug(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_CASES_SHEET, Constants.TCID, currentTestCaseID)+" -- "+currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData("Test Cases", "Runmode", currentTestCaseID));

                currentTestCaseName=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_CASES_SHEET, Constants.TCID, currentTestCaseID);

                if(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_CASES_SHEET, Constants.RUNMODE, currentTestCaseID).equals(Constants.RUNMODE_YES)){

                    APP_LOGS.debug("Executing the test case -> "+currentTestCaseName);
                    if(currentTestSuiteXLS.isSheetExist(currentTestCaseName)){
                        // RUN as many times as number of test data sets with runmode Y
                        for(currentTestDataSetID=2;currentTestDataSetID<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount(currentTestCaseName);currentTestDataSetID++)
                        {

                            resultSet = new ArrayList<String>();
                            APP_LOGS.debug("Iteration number "+(currentTestDataSetID-1));
                            // checking the runmode for the current data set
                            if(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RUNMODE, currentTestDataSetID).equals(Constants.RUNMODE_YES)){


                                // iterating through all keywords
                                executeKeywords(); // multiple sets of data
                            }
                            createXLSReport();
                        }
                    }else{
                        // iterating through all keywords
                        resultSet= new ArrayList<String>();
                        executeKeywords();// no data with the test
                        createXLSReport();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


public void executeKeywords() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {


    // iterating through all keywords
    for(currentTestStepID=2;currentTestStepID<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET);currentTestStepID++)
    for(currentTestStepID=2;currentTestStepID<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getColumnCount(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET);currentTestStepID++)

    {
        // checking TCID
        if(currentTestCaseName.equals(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.TCID, currentTestStepID))){


            data=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.DATA,currentTestStepID);


            if(data.startsWith(Constants.DATA_START_COL)){
                // read actual data value from the corresponding column
                data=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, data.split(Constants.DATA_SPLIT)[1] ,currentTestDataSetID );

            }else if(data.startsWith(Constants.CONFIG)){
                //read actual data value from config.properties
                data=CONFIG.getProperty(data.split(Constants.DATA_SPLIT)[1]);
            }else{
                //by default read actual data value from or.properties
                data=OR.getProperty(data);
            }
            object=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.OBJECT,currentTestStepID  );
           currentKeyword=currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.KEYWORD, currentTestStepID);
            APP_LOGS.debug(currentKeyword);
            // code to execute the keywords as well
            // reflection API

            for(int i=0;i<method.length;i++){

                if(method[i].getName().equals(currentKeyword)){
                    keyword_execution_result=(String)method[i].invoke(keywords,object,data);
                    APP_LOGS.debug(keyword_execution_result);
                    resultSet.add(keyword_execution_result);
                    // capture screenshot
                    capturescreenshot_method.invoke(keywords,
                            currentTestSuite+"_"+currentTestCaseName+"_TS"+currentTestStepID+"_"+(currentTestDataSetID-1),
                            keyword_execution_result);

                    //how do we call
                    // what will be the file name




                }
            }
        }
    }
}






    public void createXLSReport()
    {
    if(!isColExist)
        currentTestSuiteXLS.addColumn(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, colName);
    int index=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=currentTestSuiteXLS.getRowCount(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET);i++){

        if(currentTestCaseName.equals(currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, Constants.TCID, i))){
            if(resultSet.size()==0)
                currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, colName, i, Constants.KEYWORD_SKIP);
            else
                currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(Constants.TEST_STEPS_SHEET, colName, i, resultSet.get(index));
            index++;
        }


    }

    if(resultSet.size()==0){
        // skip
        currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RESULT, currentTestDataSetID, Constants.KEYWORD_SKIP);
        return;
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<resultSet.size();i++){
            if(!resultSet.get(i).equals(Constants.KEYWORD_PASS)){
                currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RESULT, currentTestDataSetID, resultSet.get(i));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    currentTestSuiteXLS.setCellData(currentTestCaseName, Constants.RESULT, currentTestDataSetID, Constants.KEYWORD_PASS);
    //  if(!currentTestSuiteXLS.getCellData(currentTestCaseName, "Runmode",currentTestDataSetID).equals("Y")){}

}
```

}

Below is the issue which is displayed when executing the driver script

Line151 `keyword_execution_result=(String)method[i].invoke(keywords,object,data);`

Line 107 `executeKeywords(); // multiple sets of data`

Line 63 `test.start()`

Line 51 `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(implicitWaitTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at com.totsy.test.DriverScript.executeKeywords(DriverScript.java:151)

at com.totsy.test.DriverScript.start(DriverScript.java:107)

at com.totsy.test.DriverScript.main(DriverScript.java:63)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.totsy.test.Keywords.openBrowser(Keywords.java:51)
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.totsy.test.Keywords.openBrowser(Keywords.java:51)` this shall not be ignored either. In which case what value is being assigned to `implicitWaitTime` is a curious question

Comment: 20 is the value assigned to implicit wait

Comment: can we look at the code where you are assigning the variable `implicitWaitTime` and also the `driver`. I doubt even if the driver is not created successfully you would get a `nullpointer`

Answer (score 0):

Slight doubt at `implicitWaitTime` as you clear off was its value being assigned, But since that(`20`) seems alright. You should probably ensure that the `driver` in your case is assigned a value and is created successfully during the phase of execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver.Timeouts implicitlyWait(long time, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)
```

-Check that your implicitWaitTime is returning long type value